# WebApi2 requested Image BLOB doesn't render in a React app

Tags: reactjs, image, asp.net-web-api, axios, blob

I have a WebApi2 endpoint returning FileStreamResult. Executing a jwt authorized POST request, I am able to see the picture in the response in Chrome dev tools Preview Tab in the Network panel.

Also, I am able to see the created URL but no file is displayed in the Preview tab and when I open the 'blob:http://.....' URL it opens no file. When assigned to the  also no image is displayed but the default HTML one with the alt value.

Any suggestions why the created URL doesn't work? My feeling is I am not doing something correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
    axios.create({
        baseURL: '....',
        headers: {
            'responseType':'blob', 
            'Authorization': typedJwt,
        },
    })
    .get('api/user/image/thumb100x100', {
        params: {
            imageMetadataId: user.profile.profileImage.id,
            contentType: "image/*"
            // contentType: user.profile.profileImage.contentType
        }
    }).then( 
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'image/*'});
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // here I save the blobUrl to localStorage
    );
```

...

```
<img src={localStorage.blobURL} alt="..." />
```

...

Axios Response result:

[image: Axios Response result]

...

Blob URL result:

[image: Blob URL result:]

...

Response's strange data:

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069456/how-to-read-or-convert-an-image-blob-url-into-an-image

Comment: @Roman Marusyk how should this link help me? I don't have a problem reading the file from the localStorage but rather reading it from the HTTP response and saving it there